# Azure DevOps REST API - Get agent pools for jobs?

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops

I'm using the [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to retrieve pipeline runs (aka "builds"). The build response has a bunch of good data, but it seems that the *pool* it reports only applies if the overall pipeline has a top-level pool defined.

For example, I have a pipeline that runs several parallel jobs, each one in a different self-hosted agent pool. But when I retrieve a build of this pipeline using the REST API, the only data available is for the *pipeline's* pool, which is the normal `Hosted Ubuntu 1604` response you get for Microsoft-hosted builds - there's no mention of any of the self-hosted agent pools that did all the work.

I've tried drilling down into different sections (including the stage and task queries). The task level will eventually show the *name* of the agent used, but it's just a string, so it's not easy to infer the agent pool used unless you happen to name your agents in a specific way.

Is there any way to drill down into the individual "jobs" that ran as part of a pipeline and see what agent pools they were run on, using the REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Build` response contains a link timeline (under `Links` field). [image: visual-studio-reference-links-in-response]

You can form it like this: `https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_apis/build/builds/<buildId>/Timeline`

The Json response has useful info for each job/task including `queueId`

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks for the note about queueId!  I didn't notice that.  In my particular case though, that queueId isn't useful because that queueId is the queueId of the "pipeline" (a Microsoft-hosted agent), not the queueIds for either of my self-hosted agent queues that actually run my jobs.

Comment: I have a multi-stage pipeline where one of the stage is using self hosted agents and I'm able to see the queueId for both (one of the task has the MS Hosted agents queueId and the other task has my self-hosted agents queueId)

Comment: I discounted the queueId too soon! It turns out each link from your "poolId" to a project is a separate "queueId", so using the timeline queueId, you just need to work back to the linked projectId, and you can assemble a list of all agent pools the job used.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

at present, our Rest API cannot help us drill down into the individual "jobs" that ran as part of a pipeline and see what agent pools they were run on. This Rest Api is used to find the default settings about your pipeline.
As the work around, we can use the api: [Builds - Get Build Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20log?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), and find the agent's name, like this:
[image]